# Are "Identify this" questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Are "Identify this manga" or "Identify this anime" questions on topic for the site?  I'm wondering if we could incorporate a similar policy as that on [SciFi.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/are-book-movie-tv-series-identification-questions-allowed).

Comment: I think that adopting the SF policy is a good idea.

Answer (score 10):

Agreeing with @JNat, I think the SF policy is a very good one for a site which has a medium. You may catch a glimpse of an anime or manga somewhere and think it's good, and then try to find it again. Or you may want to reread that one manga you read at a bookstore when you were bored, but you don't remember the name, just the general theme / specific traits about the characters (this is the case for me, currently).

Comment: I tend to lean to this resolution, as Identify This questions have worked fairly well on SciFi.

Comment: I agree.  SF's policy works wonders.

Answer (score 1):

***No***, they should definitely be off topic.

I wrote a rather huge essay on this topic on Gaming.SE. Rather than re-post it here, I will [just link to that one](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4118/1719). All of the points remain the same whether applied to games, anime, movies, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree 100%.  Some of your points are spot-on, but I don't think that they're wildly off-topic here.

Comment: Answers to IT questions need not be guesses here (which was your biggest complaint in that essay). Anime and Manga are visual formats, and for at least some of the questions the questioner could include or link to a picture of the series in question. I'll also point out that your essay, while it makes good points, is only the third-highest rated answer on the linked question, and anyone reading it should also take the time to read at least a a few of the other opinions there, which also make good points.

Comment: Identifying stories are okay in the Sci-Fi stackexchange.  In my point of view anime and manga are closer to stories than to games.

Comment: @Blue The medium has no bearing on why IT are problematic. SFF and Arqade just have differing site policies.